# How do you reference a zul component with an dynamic id, like id="calendarDecorate_${vmStatus.index}"?

Tags: zk

I have method in class

```
public class CalendarDecorate {
 public void setDays(final boolean checkDays){
  //code
}}
```

In my zul file, i have a own component for this class:

```
<div>
  <calendarDecorate id="calendarDecorate_${vmStatus.index}"</calendarDecorate>
  <combobox onChange="calendarDecorate_${vmStatus.index}.setDays(payment.Code)"/>
</div>
```

Is there a notation that allows this reference `calendarDecorator_${vmPaymentStatus.index}.setDays(payment.Code)` to work?

Comment: Looks like the problem is about addressing multiple calendarDecorates from comboboxes's onChange handler. Can you add the error you got from the statement: calendarDecorator_${vmPaymentStatus.index}.setDays(payment.Code) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is just one `<calendarDecorate>`,  you can just wire by component type

`@Wire("calendardecorate")`

Since you append an index in id, I suppose there are multiple `<calendarDecorate>`. You can 
[Wiring a Collection](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/MVC/Controller/Wire_Components#Wiring_a_Collection) and reference one of them with index, `vmStatus.index`.

If you develop in MVVM pattern, usually you don't need to get a component reference. Just bind the corresponding property to the attribute e.g.

`<calendarDecorate days="@load(vm.payment.code">`